# Onboarding Screen Animations

Tags: android, android-animation

How to achieve a very cool looking on-boarding screen animations like the attached one.And which technology is used for it. is it Lottie Animation/video that developers control on Swipe gestures, or it is achieved by coding.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The animation you have picked is from [this source](https://dribbble.com/shots/3282853-App-Onboarding) is basically a UI design, which is mainly done by either Sketch or Adobe XD

So the main task is to transform this Sketch App UI Design to Android XML. There is a lot of tutorial in youtube [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_WnEiO5nao) from where you can do this.

Then you need to know some basic about XML animation how its work with java. From [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHDLexobRMA) and [this link](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/) you will get some idea.

Then Finally you need to build an intro slider on your own. You can follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byLKoPgB7yA) and [this post](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/)

but there is some library also by which you can do this.

You can use [App Intro](https://github.com/AppIntro/AppIntro) and [material-intro-screen](https://github.com/TangoAgency/material-intro-screen)